# How to convert from NPN expression to tree?

Tags: c, struct, tree, npn

I have been developing about NPN expressions in C. The problem is that I should create I function which takes a string and creates the tree according to these examples:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zkJ8.png)

I have started the function, using strtok in order to take the differents token of the string:

```
T_Tree readgenerate(char string []) {
    char *token = strtok(string," ");
    double value;
    T_Tree tree;
    while(token != NULL) {
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
        char disc = token[0];
        tree->discriminant = disc;
        if(disc == '*' || disc == '+' || disc == '-' || disc == '/' || disc == 'p') {
            tree = insertBoth(disc, NULL, NULL); 
        }
    }
}
```

However, I dont know how to complete it, and I would appreciatte u to help me.

.............................................................................................................

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.